# Call a javascript function from another file in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, import

I'm trying to build a chrome plugin that analyzes the URL and runs some functions depending on it. The js file is like of the format

```
function fn1(){
    //some logic
}

function fn2(){
    //some logic
}

if (url == 'site1'){
    fn1();

} else if (url == 'site2'){
    fn2();

}
```

Now the problem is, fn1 and fn2 are fairly large and for readability, I'd like to move them to another file and import them. I have tried

```
import {fn1} from './file.js';
```

This gives an error

> cannot use import outside of a module

Any other ideas on how to do this? Thanks

Comment: You have to use export to be able to use your function with the import statement. Simply write export {fn1, fn2} inside of your file.js file. It shoud work afterwards :)

Comment: Nope, still getting 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module'